# How to keep running my while loop if an empty String is entered in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, nan, string

```
var o = prompt("Enter a Number");
while (isNaN(o)) {
    o = prompt("Not a number! Enter a Number");
}
o = parseInt(o);
```

If I just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and send an empty string to `o`, it returns `NaN` when I print `var o`. I've tried 
`||` instance of string and get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = prompt("Enter a Number");
while (isNaN(o) || o === '' ) {
    o = prompt("Not a number! Enter a Number");
}
o = parseInt(o);
```

Try the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = prompt("Enter a Number");
while (isNaN(o) || o.trim() == '' ) {
    o = prompt("Not a number! Enter a Number");
}
o = parseInt(o);
```

The extra `o.trim() == ''` condition will ensure that an empty input, as well as just spaces, will trigger the condition again. Without the trim function, this will permit just spaces to go through.

Comment: You might say what is different from what was posted.